# BIM360 Issues - Snapshot URN Image

Tags: autodesk-forge

in BIM360 I recovered the issues with the specific issues method described at this link
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/

For each issue I have "snapshot_urn" as information (if a markup has been added to the issue, otherwise NULL).

[ISSUE snapshot URN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQSPz.png)

Is it possible to get the snapshot image via snapshot_urn? What API should I use?

TIA
Alder

Comment: As far as I know, the snapshot images are managed in the oss bucket ( as shown in your screenshot ng-issues-XXX). the bucket is not accessible for public. I am checking with engineer team if they have any latest information.

Comment: Thanks @xiaodong-liang, let me know if there are any news

Comment: I have to finally logged an internal ticket with the inquiry: SCCOM-9750
API question: How to download the snapshot by snap_urn. I will watch the ticket and get back if I get any information. Appreciate for your patience and understanding!

Comment: Hi @xiaodong-liang, any news about the ticket?

Comment: Hi Alder, my sincerer apology for the late response. I did not even notice your message. You may have knownBIM360 Issue v2 API has been released, unfortunately, this is still a gap with Issue V2 API. we are pushing engineer team to expose the support. I am checking with engineer team if they have any update with the wish.