# How to get image from snapshot urn?

Tags: autodesk-forge

[BIM360 Issues - Snapshot URN Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840571/bim360-issues-snapshot-urn-image)

Is it possible to get the snapshot image via snapshot_urn? I could get snapshot_urn from BIM360 Issues API and trying to get download link from Data Management API, but I got 403 error "reason": "No namespace provided".

```
"snapshotUrn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:ng-issues-prod-0df8decb-8ab7-4985-b1cd-f79ad844e1db/1545c7b6-8c96-480e-9800-b494f69e9b65"
```

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/ng-issues-prod-0df8decb-8ab7-4985-b1cd-f79ad844e1db/objects/1545c7b6-8c96-480e-9800-b494f69e9b65/signeds3download
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is still a gap with Issue V2 API. but we are pushing engineer team to expose the support. The short information of the background is: the snapshot data is managed in the specific bucket which requires to enable the access. That is why you got the error.  I am checking with engineer team if they have any update with the wish.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thanks for the reply. I hope they give us access in the future updates!

Comment: hi, the latest update is : engineer team is working on this feature. I cannot guarantee the exact time it would be supported, though.  thank you for your patience

Comment: Thanks for the update! Please let me know when the team expect the date to finish this feature. Thank you for your support.